# First Activity Executes But Doesn't Show

Tags: android, android-activity, splash-screen

I have a small problem with an app I'm developping.. My first activity reads data from the device (or fetch them on the internet and save them locally) and then starts the second activity that uses those data. If the data cannot be loaded, it stays on that activity and show that the data couldn't be loaded.

The thing is, when that first activity starts, if the datas are available and all, it doesn't show the activity. All you see is a blank page, then the second activity comes up.

My data retreiving is done in an async task and I wait until the task is done to start the second activity. That's why I don't the reason why my first activity is just blank when it should be my splash screen...

First Activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar));
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title)).setText(R.string.toolbar_loading);
    findViewById(R.id.toolbar_search).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_text);
    retryButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.main_button);
    retryButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mTracker = ((MyApp) getApplication()).getDefaultTracker();
    ((MyApp) getApplication()).setServerInformation(SharedPrefManager.getServer(this));
    // Modification des options si l'application en est à sa première
    // exécution
    if (SharedPrefManager.isFirstRun(this)) {
        SharedPrefManager.setFirstTimePrefs(this, Utility.retreiveLanguage());
        Log.d(LoginActivity.class.getName(), "First run triggered.");
    }
    ((MyApp)getApplication()).configureSocketHandler(false, MainActivity.this);
}
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    Log.d(MainActivity.class.getName(), "ON RESUME");
    mTracker.setScreenName(MainActivity.class.getName());
    mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
    ((MyApp) getApplication()).onResume(this);
    if(options == null){
        loadRegions();
    }else{
        startRegionActivity(null);
    }
}
private void loadRegions() {
    if(options == null) {
        options = OptionsManager.getInstance().getOptions();
    }
    Log.d(MainActivity.class.getName(), "Trying to load options ");
    if(options != null) {
        startRegionActivity(null);
    }else{
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.region_error);
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.region_error_message);
        builder.setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Do nothing
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
        findViewById(R.id.toolbar_login).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        retryButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: share the code please!

Comment: I'm assuming there is code that you aren't showing?

Comment: Code is there, need something more?

Comment: you need to start the 2nd activity out of `onPostExecute()` method. The trick is, that `doInBackground()` should do nothing or `sleep()` if the data are present

Comment: on create is never finished hence before onResume can initiate and show up the contentview of the activity the next activity is triggered. re-check your async-task

Comment: I would assume you start the second activity by creating an `intent` and calling `startActivity(intent)`, yet I do not see that anywhere in the code you posted.  Also as a side note it might save you some time to adopt the best practice of using a `TAG` in your `Log` calls. Make a global variable: `public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();` and use it like this: `Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");`.

Comment: **"...an async task and I wait until the task is done"** : Do you understand what 'async' means? Basically you do *NOT* wait for an asynchronous operation - that's the whole point - you set it going and it does whatever it needs to do  in a separate thread. Waiting for an `AsyncTask` to complete is a pointless exercise.

Comment: The thing is, my Async task is created in my onResume, so my onCreate as plenty of time to finish...

Comment: @dequec64 **".. my Async task is created in my onResume, so.."** but I don't see your use of a `AsynTask` in `onResune()`

Comment: It's in loadRegions(), the OptionsManager.getInstance().getOptions() will start the AsynTask

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my problem with a simple yet weird way..

As I told you earlier, my onCreate and onStart have time to finish before I start my Async task (I logged them to make sure). The problem was, I think, that the Async task was launched too quickly for Android to refresh the UI with the one from the activity. To ensure that it has time to appear before launching the Async task, I encapsulated my method calling the task in a runnable and had a worker execute the runnable after 2 seconds of wait time:

```
if(options == null){
        Runnable task = new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                loadRegions();
            }
        };
        worker.schedule(task, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }else{
        Runnable task = new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                startRegionActivity(null);
            }
        };
        worker.schedule(task, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
```

With my worker declaration at the beginning of my class:

```
private final ScheduledExecutorService worker = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
```

Hope this could help someone in the future!